# "No ad config" while adding admob bannner/interstitial Ad in Android Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, admob, ads, adsense

I just implemented code for showing interstitial ad and banner ad but I'm getting "No ad config error code : 3". The app is a client project and its something of a pirated stuff. Yesterday the app was working fine on emulator (even with production ad ids) but today in emulator and in real device both app isn't loading..
[Manifest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMeuv.png)

Banner Ad Code -

```
val mAdView = binding.bannerAd
        val adRequest = AdRequest.Builder().build()
        mAdView.adListener = object: AdListener() {
            override fun onAdLoaded() {
                // Code to be executed when an ad finishes loading.
            }

            override fun onAdFailedToLoad(adError : LoadAdError) {
                Log.e("AD", "BANNER ADD FAILED TO LOAD $adError")
            }

            override fun onAdOpened() {
                // Code to be executed when an ad opens an overlay that
                // covers the screen.
            }

            override fun onAdClicked() {
                // Code to be executed when the user clicks on an ad.
            }

            override fun onAdLeftApplication() {
                // Code to be executed when the user has left the app.
            }

            override fun onAdClosed() {
                // Code to be executed when the user is about to return
                // to the app after tapping on an ad.
            }
        }

        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest)
```

Interstitial Ad Code -

```
var mInterstitialAd: InterstitialAd? = null
    var TAG = "AD"
    var adRequest = AdRequest.Builder().build()
    InterstitialAd.load(
        context,
        "ca-app-pub-xxxxx/xxxxxx", // I Have real id here
        adRequest,
        object : InterstitialAdLoadCallback() {
            override fun onAdFailedToLoad(adError: LoadAdError) {
                Log.e("AD", adError?.message)
                mInterstitialAd = null
            }

            override fun onAdLoaded(interstitialAd: InterstitialAd) {
                mInterstitialAd = interstitialAd

                mInterstitialAd?.fullScreenContentCallback = object: FullScreenContentCallback() {
                    override fun onAdDismissedFullScreenContent() {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Ad was dismissed.")
                    }

                    override fun onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent(adError: AdError?) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Ad failed to show.")
                    }

                    override fun onAdShowedFullScreenContent() {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Ad showed fullscreen content.")
                        mInterstitialAd = null;
                    }
                }

                if (mInterstitialAd != null) {
                    mInterstitialAd?.show(activity)
                } else {
                }
            }
        }
    )
```

Comment: Hi, I am also facing the same issue. Any luck? Did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is server side issue, please once try to change package name and then test.